# stuck implementing k means in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, k-means

i am having trouble implementing k means. Specifically, i am having trouble plotting points with different colours, green for one cluster and red for the other. My code logically makes sense, i just need someone to point out why matplotlib is not plotting the points.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random, math


def plotRandomCentroid(maxx, minx, maxy, miny): # Function to create a random centroid
    return [random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy)]


x = [4.4, 3.2, 4.6, 4, 4.1, 2.9, 2.9] # Weight data
y = [31, 19, 32, 25, 29, 17, 11] # Height data

plt.title("Big Dogs and Small Dogs")
plt.ylabel("Height (cm)")
plt.xlabel("Weight (kg)")


k = 2 # Centroid data
centroid1 = [plotRandomCentroid(max(x), min(x), max(y), min(y))]
centroid2 = [plotRandomCentroid(max(x), min(x), max(y), min(y))]


plt.scatter(centroid1[0][0], centroid1[0][1], color = "maroon") # Scatters centroids
plt.scatter(centroid2[0][0], centroid1[0][1], color = "green")


for j in xrange(1): # Updating centroid positions
    cent1hyp = math.sqrt(centroid1[0][0]**2 + centroid1[0][1]**2)
    cent2hyp = math.sqrt(centroid2[0][0]**2 + centroid2[0][1]**2)
    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        pointx = x[i-1]
        pointy = y[i-1]
        pointhyp = math.sqrt(pointx**2 + pointy**2)
        cent1dis = cent1hyp - pointhyp
        cent2dis = cent2hyp - pointhyp
        if abs(cent1dis) < abs(cent2dis):
            plt.plot(pointx, pointy, color = "lime")
        else:
            plt.plot(pointx, pointy, color = "red")


plt.show()
```

I am now  going to walk you through my code. So first of all i import my libraries and create a function that creates a centroid within the range of my data. Next i include the data in x and y lists, and create some labels for the graph. Then i decide how many clusters i want (i havent found a use for the variable 'k' yet so i might delete it) and generate a centroid in 'centroid1' and 'centroid2'. After this, i plotted them. The centroids have a darker green and red, and now i am trying to plot the data points in a lighter colour of each.The main 'for j in xrange' loop will be repeated until convergence. 'cent1hyp' and 'cent2hyp' works out the hypotenuse of the centroids, or in other words the distance from the point (0, 0). Next i looped through the data, and the following code occurs for each data point. I created variables 'pointx' and 'pointy' to temporarily hold the x and y coordinates for each point. Then i worked out the point's hypotenuse, or distance from coordinate (0, 0) with pythagoras's theorem. If you are with me, you should know that i now have the hypotenuse for my data point, centroid 1 and 2. To work out which cluster the point should be a member of, i rearranged pythagoras's theorem to work out the distances between the data point and centroids, based around the hypotenuses. Now... here's where its going wrong... i wrote an if-else statement to plot the points either light green or light red depending on which centroid is closer. When i run my code, only the centroids are being plotted. Help! Hopefully i have given enough detail for you to help me with. If you dont like something about my QUESTION, please ask me about it rather than down vote my question as this is just lazy and pathetic. I have a low reputation so a bad question will majorly impact my account. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: There is no error log, matplotlib only plots the centroids instead of the centroids and the datapoints @Akash

Comment: If I have understood, you are plotting a single point at a time in your loop.  plt.plot will plot the lines between points, which obviously don't exist if you only have a single point.  Try adding 'o' as an argument to plt.plot, to tell it you want a circle marker.